# In Matlab, how can I filter a structure by calendar year and insert the elements of interest into a new nested structure?

Tags: matlab, sorting, nested, structure

In MATLAB, I am trying to filter out the structure **nxtPdOut** by calendar year '**m**' (**nxtPdOut(nn).datePdLow**) and inserting each **nxtPdOut(nn)** element into the new structure **yoyComp(m)**.  Hopefully this isn't too confusing but I'll try to explain further.

The following code will build out the structure **nxtPdOut** (note: this structure is not static and will change with additional years that are unknown):

```
nxtPdOut(1).datePdLow = 734505;
nxtPdOut(1).a = 111;
nxtPdOut(1).b = 222;
nxtPdOut(2).datePdLow = 734510;
nxtPdOut(2).a = 333;
nxtPdOut(2).b = 444;
nxtPdOut(3).datePdLow = 734868;
nxtPdOut(3).a = 888;
nxtPdOut(3).b = 887;

nxtPdOut(4).datePdLow = 734869;
nxtPdOut(4).a = 555;
nxtPdOut(4).b = 666;
nxtPdOut(5).datePdLow = 734872;
nxtPdOut(5).a = 777;
nxtPdOut(5).b = 888;
nxtPdOut(6).datePdLow = 734880;
nxtPdOut(6).a = 999;
nxtPdOut(6).b = 1010;

nxtPdOut(7).datePdLow = 735235;
nxtPdOut(7).a = 999;
nxtPdOut(7).b = 1010;
nxtPdOut(8).datePdLow = 735300;
nxtPdOut(8).a = 999;
nxtPdOut(8).b = 1010;
```

The following code will determine **m** years to sort by (note: **m** years will not be constant and will always change depending on numYrs):

```
numYrs = 2;
tDay = datevec(date);
for m=1:1:numYrs+1
    if m == 1
        yrs(:,:,m) = [tDay(1,1) tDay(1,2)-tDay(1,2)+1 tDay(1,3)-...
            tDay(1,3)+1 0 0 0];
    else
        yrs(:,:,m) =  [yrs(1,1,1)-m+1 1 1 0 0 0];
    end
end
jj = size(yrs(1,1,:));
for j=1:1:jj(3)
    yrsStr(1,j) = datenum(yrs(:,:,j));
end
yrsStr = fliplr(yrsStr); %ascending serial numbers

% Output for yrsStr: 
% yrsStr = [734504      734869      735235]
% FYI:  (datestr(yrsStr(1)) == 01-Jan-2011; 
%    datestr(yrsStr(2)) == 01-Jan-2012; 
%    datestr(yrsStr(1)) == 01-Jan-2013
```

I tried different combinations of the following code, but am stuck and do not know how to finish it.

```
nn = 1;
for n = 1:length(yrsStr)-1
    yoyComp(n).signals = nxtPdOut(nn).(nxtPdOut.datePdLow >= yrsStr(n) &...
        nxtPdOut(nn).datePdLow < yrsStr(n+1));
end

    while nn <= numel(nxtPdOut)
        if nxtPdOut(nn)
            yoyComp(n).signals = nxtPdOut
```

I am trying to filter **nxtPdOut** by calendar year and placing the results into the new structure **yoyComp**.  For example, 734504 <= elements < 734869 into yoyComp(1); 734869 <= elements < 735235 into yoyComp(2); and, finally, elements >= 735235 into yoyComp(3).  Please refer to the following for the desired output:

```
yoyComp(1).out(1).datePdLow = 734505;
yoyComp(1).out(1).a = 111;
yoyComp(1).out(1).b = 222;
yoyComp(1).out(2).datePdLow = 734510;
yoyComp(1).out(2).a = 333;
yoyComp(1).out(2).b = 444;
yoyComp(1).out(3).datePdLow = 734868;
yoyComp(1).out(3).a = 888;
yoyComp(1).out(3).b = 887;

yoyComp(2).out(1).datePdLow = 734869;
yoyComp(2).out(1).a = 555;
yoyComp(2).out(1).b = 666;
yoyComp(2).out(2).datePdLow = 734872;
yoyComp(2).out(2).a = 777;
yoyComp(2).out(2).b = 888;
yoyComp(2).out(3).datePdLow = 734880;
yoyComp(2).out(3).a = 999;
yoyComp(2).out(3).b = 1010;

yoyComp(3).out(1).datePdLow = 735235;
yoyComp(3).out(1).a = 999;
yoyComp(3).out(1).b = 1010;
yoyComp(3).out(2).datePdLow = 735300;
yoyComp(3).out(2).a = 999;
yoyComp(3).out(2).b = 1010;
```

I would appreciate any ideas/suggestions to continue.  I know how to filter/extract from a matrix, but I do not know how to do it by structure.  Please advise.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a final `inf` term to your `yrsStr` and then you can use the amended code at the bottom of this answer to create your `yoyComp` structure.  The main change I've made has been to use logical indexing, and capture the output of the structure's fields by surrounding the expression with square brackets (see `[nxtPdOut.datePdLow]`).

Here's a basic demonstration of what I mean

For the structure

```
a(1).b = 5
a(2).b = 6
a(3).b = 7
```

You can interact with it in the following way, either:

```
>> a.b

ans =

     5


ans =

     6


ans =

     7
```

Or by capturing the results into a vector:

```
>> [a.b]

ans =

     5     6     7
```

For your code specifically, the following gives the result that you described in the question:

```
yrsStr = [yrsStr, inf];

nn = 1;
for n = 1:length(yrsStr)-1
    yoyComp(n).signals = nxtPdOut([nxtPdOut.datePdLow] >= yrsStr(n) &...
        [nxtPdOut.datePdLow] < yrsStr(n+1));
end
```

Note that I've deleted that I've deleted the

```
while nn <= numel(nxtPdOut)
    if nxtPdOut(nn)
        yoyComp(n).signals = nxtPdOut
```

section of your code since I'm not sure what it was doing.

Comment: This works perfectly.  And I appreciate the explanation! Thanks.

Comment: I have a quick question.  Why does the code `yoyComp(n).signals = nxtPdOut([nxtPdOut.datePdLow] >= yrsStr(n) &...
        [nxtPdOut.datePdLow] < yrsStr(n+1));
` bring in all the elements **datePdLow** & **a** & **b** and not just ONLY **datePdLow**?